# datetime conversion failed when converting date or time from character string SQL (c#)

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to get my program to work, it is using parameters in an SQL query to add it to the database. When I run the program it comes up with "datetime conversion failed when converting date or time from character string". I have tried many types of coding to make it work and all have failed. The SQL code itself works. It's simply the conversion that is breaking. I have tried multiple other posts on here and none have worked. Here's my code:

```cs
string query = $"UPDATE[***].[***]  SET [***]= '@FName', [***]= '@SName', [***] = '@Modified', [***] = '@Arrival', [***] = '@Departure'  where [Id] = '{id}'; ";
Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
parameters.Add("@FName", record.guestGiven);
parameters.Add("@SName", record.guestSurname);
parameters.Add("@Modified", record.ModifiedDate.ToString());
parameters.Add("@Arrival", Convert.ToString(record.arrivalDate));
parameters.Add("@Departure", Convert.ToString(record.departureDate));
mySuilvision.InsertData(query, parameters);
```

I also tried to do the following

```cs
parameters.Add("@Modified", record.ModifiedDate.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM:ss));
```

and all it came up with is the same error and for the last piece of code the VS error was "cannot convert from string to system.IFormatProvider. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why you convert a `DateTime` to string if you want to save a `DateTime`? Your parameter dictionary should be a `List<SqlParameter>`. Then tell the database that you are passing a `DateTime` and assign the value. Everything will work and is safe.

Comment: @TimSchmelter they are stored as string in the database, there is no dateTime. Im unsure why but thats how the system has been setup by someone else

Comment: it is a RMS system, this is setup by an external company

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your SQL:

```
string query = $"UPDATE[***].[***]  SET [***]= @FName, [***]= @SName, [***] = @Modified, [***] = @Arrival, [***] = @Departure where [Id] = '{id}'; ";
```

By putting the parameter names in quotes they are treated as string literals, which won't work.

Also, why are you adding the ID as a literal? You should add that as a parameter too.

Comment: so in the parameters code, can it be default ? or do i need to keep the .Tostring() on the end ? i will give this a test now

Comment: I would typically pass the parameters in as their actual types, so I'd pass a Date parameter in as an actual Date, not a date in string format. This allows everything to work when you might have a date format that you weren't expecting. However you're using a Dictionary<String,String> to hold your parameters and passing that to a Class. So it depends on if you can change how that class works. I'd normally either use a List<SQLParameter> or add the Parameters directly to the SQLCommand object.